# Работа с Landing page

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день, коллеги! Нужны пара советов новичку, т.е. мне.

Сейчас разбираю структуру  Landing page.

Скачал с одного сайта Шаблон-образец Landing page и не могу понять два вопроса:

1. Почему в оригинале **logo.png** (2 сотки) не имеют белых границ по краям на сайте, а сохраненный вместо него холодильник, тоже в формате `*.png` имеет белые границы, как в оригинале. В чем причина?
2. Как именно при уменьшении экрана исчезает верхнее меню и вместо него появляется кнопка с 3 полосками, содержащее выпадающее меню.

Смотрю вложенный **responsive.css**, в нем в основном уменьшаются тексты и  кнопки.
А код выпадающей кнопки в него не входит. Где искать эту кнопку? В CSS-файлах или в JS-файлах?

Это код выпадающей кнопки:

```
<div class="container-fluid nav-bar">

    <div class="navbar-header"> // код выпадающей кнопки
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
</div>    


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> // код верхнего меню
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home">Домой</a></li>
        <li><a href="#features">Функции</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Описание</a></li>
        <li><a href="#testimonials">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Цены</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

А это код **responsive.css**:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.banner h3 {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 105px;
}
.banner h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.banner p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
.download-btn {
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.features-btn {
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contact {
  height: 900px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.features p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.features h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.details p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
    .details ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.feature-detail h4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.feature-detail p {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.pricing-slide p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.item h6 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.item h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.item img {
  margin-bottom: 95px;
}
.download p {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.download button{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contact p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.contact-heading img {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разбейте свой вопрос на несколько

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы, видимо, сохранили свой холодильник вместе с фоном (подложкой).
2. Это называется - [адаптивность](https://webref.ru/layout/bootstrap/responsive), которая реализуется с помощью медиа запросов (media queries).
3. Где искать эту кнопку? - В html:

   ```
   // код выпадающей кнопки
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   ```

   `icon-bar` - это как раз те самые 3 полоски, стилизованные с помощью `.css`. А вот функционал (при нажатии раскрывается меню) реализован с помощью `.js`.

   Появляется на телефонах и исчезает на десктопах - адаптивность, которая реализуется в `.css` вот такими конструкциями\стилями:

   ```
   @media (min-width: NNpx) { ... }
   ```
4. Верстка данного лендинга осуществлена с помощью фреймверка - [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

О верстке, адаптивности и многом другом Вы можете почитать и разобраться на [htmlbook](https://webref.ru/frontpage)

Comment: 1) Спасибо за 1 ответ. А кроме фотошопа еще кто-то может убрать с фотографии подложку? Есть какие-нибудь бесплатные простые фото-редакторы?

Comment: 2) А вот 2 вопрос Вы не поняли: Я знаю что там адаптивность, именно поэтому я привел в пример "responsive.css". Мне по коду непонятно, где именно произошло срабатывание (убрать верхнее меню, а вместо него поставить кнопку с 3 полосками). Где искать это срабатывание? И по какому значению? Может по классу "navbar-toggle collapsed"?

Comment: 3) И новый общий вопрос:  а на чем вообще чаще всего делают Landing Page профессиональные PHP-программисты? Видел видео по Adobe MUSE, он пользуется популярностью? А Вы на чем делаете?

Comment: @AibekSydygaliev, `@media (min-width: 768px){ .navbar-toggle { display: none;  } }` и это же правило `@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }` для списка\навигации. Дизайн по правилу "от меньшего к большему", т.е. сначала стили пишутся под меньшие разрешения экранов (изначально кнопка `display: block;` ), а потом медиа запросами задаются стили уже для девайсов с большим разрешением (при 768px и больше кнопку скрываем а список делаем видимым и горизонтальным `display: block;`  );

Comment: Ясно. А что насчет первого вопроса? Есть какие-нибудь бесплатные простые фото-редакторы, вместо фото-шопа?

Comment: @AibekSydygaliev, фотошоп в верстке незаменим, просто посмотрите пару видео уроков по работе с ним. Но как альтернативf - avocode можете посмотреть.

Comment: ОК. Спасибо за ответы!